# Byte and Bit addressable 8051

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

## 8051 SFRs

`'P0,SP, DPL & DPH'` have their byte addresses `80h,81h,82h,83h`. Since `P0` is bit addressable, `P0.0 - P0.7` has bit addresses `80h - 87h`. But, how it's gonna distinguish the addresses `P0.1(81h) & SP(81h), P0.2(82h) & DPL(82h), P0.3(83h) & DPH(83h)` …?

Answer (score 0):

Byte addresses and bit addresses are never used in the same instruction. 
So while

```
mov SP, #5    ; mov 81h, #5
mov P0.1, C     ; setb 81h
```

both have the address 81h and both are written as `mov`, the first one is assembled as `0x75 0x81 0x5` and the second `0x91 0x81`. To the processor, 0x75 and 0x91 mean entirely different things, namely, `move the the value in the 3rd byte of this instruction to the address in the second byte of this instruction`, and `move the carry flag to the bit address in the second byte of this instruction`. The assembler knows that `mov addr, #imm` and `mov bit, C` need to be encoded differently, and the processor really doesn't care how they're written because it doesn't see the source code at all.